# Grails application doesn't automatically start in browser with grails run-app

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

For some reason my grails application no longer starts a browser with the webpage displayed when doing a grails run-app. It always did before. There is no errors or anything, it just no longer auto-starts the application. I haven't changed any code unless git corrupted something. Anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: Grails does not start a browser - usually your IDE takes care of this.

Comment: I'm running IntelliJ and trying to figure out where in Settings this is defined but not having much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails does not start a browser - usually your IDE takes care of this.

On IntelliJ you can enable this behaviour (`Launch Browser`) under your `Run Configuration`.

[image: 1]

1. Click on `Edit Configurations…` here

[image: 2]

2. Enable `Launch Browser`